# jquery flexigrid - rows per page

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I've started to use this jquery flexigrid and so far it seems fine. http://flexigrid.info/

The problem I'm curious about is the "rp" setting or rows per page.

In the dropdown box I've only seem to have the options 10,15,20,25, & 40.

If I set it to these options no prob, but if I set it to a number that's not there then it defaults to 10, rather annoyingly.

I see in exampel 3 of on the website for this control, a "50" option is available.

Is there a limit on this control or have I missed something here.

Thanks,

```
                                url: 'get_item_data.aspx',
                                    dataType: 'xml',
                                    <%=display_item_details %>,
                                        sortorder: "asc",
                                    usepager: true,
                                    useRp: true,
                                    rp: 40,
                                    showTableToggleBtn: false,
                                    width: 910,
                                    height: 400,
                                }
```

Comment: you should remove the comma after the last value - IE wont like this for starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Flexigrid source, it allows only these values by default. You can however change this by setting the rpOptions as an array with the values that you want.

```
 url: 'get_item_data.aspx',
                                dataType: 'xml',
                                <%=display_item_details %>,
                                    sortorder: "asc",
                                usepager: true,
                                useRp: true,
                                rp: 40,
                                rpOptions: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                                showTableToggleBtn: false,
                                width: 910,
                                height: 400,
                            }
```